# Put intent object in Intent putExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent

Since intent object is Parcelable, is it safe to put intent object as extra param on Intent putExtra method?

for example:

```
val intentAsParam = Intent(context, Activity1::class.java)


val intent = Intent(context, Activity2::class.java)
intent.putExtra("PARAM_INTENT", intentAsParam)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: why would you want to pass intents as extras ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody on Activity2, I will do startActivity(intentAsParam) later on.

Comment: so, the only thing you need to know is where you'll be going to, right ? so you could in theory pass in a string and just use the string to determine which intent to build ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes, do you have any recommendation for that?

Comment: why don't you have a string in object class and update that to any activity you want to later goto , and use that as a indication , or like above comment suggest just pass the name of activity as a string rather than trying to pass a intent. or you can also use back stack.

Comment: @ZaidZakir thanks for your reply, but is it really better solution? I think using reflection from string class name also has some drawbacks.

Comment: ok valid concern, so then just pass a string in intent and not the whole intent and have a enum class which will have meaning for all these strings and you can use it to refer in future as to what that string means. when you need to use it for redirection. and maybe ask it to return the activity or fragment name?